# Powershell: All MAC Address as string combined

Tags: windows, powershell

Currently, I get with this command all my mac addresses from the PowerShell:

```
getmac /s $computer /FO TABLE /NH
```

It looks like this:

```
PS C:\Users\User> getmac /s $computer /FO TABLE /NH

F8-5E-A0-2B-C4-5B   Nicht zutreffend
94-8D-95-41-5F-57   Medien ausgeworfen
F8-5E-A0-2B-C4-5F   Medien ausgeworfen
08-3A-88-5C-03-28   Medien ausgeworfen
```

Now, I want to combine all addresses to a string like this:

```
F8-5E-A0-2B-C4-5B / 94-8D-95-41-5F-57 / F8-5E-A0-2B-C4-5F / 08-3A-88-5C-03-28
```

I know that I must use `join` but I don't know how.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Where-Object macaddress ).macaddress -join ' / '`

Comment: Amazing thank you so much

Comment: You may also use `$output -replace '\s.*$' -join ' / '`

Answer (score 0):

Using `getmac`:

```
(getmac /FO TABLE /NH) -ne '' -replace '\s.*$' -join ' / '
```

The `getmac.exe` program is considered external and its output is converted to an array of strings within PowerShell. As a result, you will need to parse strings for your desired result.

Since `-replace` uses regex, `\s` matches a space and `.*` matches all characters until `$` (end of each string).

---

Using `Get-NetAdapter`:

```
(Get-NetAdapter).MacAddress -join ' / '
```

Using a PowerShell cmdlet, you return a rich object with properties that can be referenced, filtered, and parsed as needed.